# Open New Tab & Search in Chome w/ Selenium+Python

Tags: windows, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

Python3/Windows10/PyCharm/Selenium/Chrome

Hello, I am trying to open a tab in chrome, navigate to bing, search for a term, open a new tab, navigate to bing, and search for a different term.

1. This works for the first three search terms, but i get an index error on search term 4.
2. Search term 3 opens in a "pop out tab" in chrome, but does search.
3. Search term 4 opens in a "pop out tab" in chrome, but gets error.
4. driver.implicitly_wait(3) does not appear to work or slow down the program.

I have several hundred search terms saved in an excel file, I'm trying to automate the search from that spreadsheet (in groups) but am afraid that my code might not be able to scale to that.

any advice is greatly appreciated:)

```
print ("Hello, world!")
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driverwebdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users")

#search term 1 denver broncos
#this opens chrome, navigates to bing, searches for "denver broncos"
driver.get("https://bing.com/")
driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("denver broncos")
driver.find_element_by_name("go").click()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
#driver.implicitly_wait(3)

#search term 2 mad men
#this creates a new tab
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.bing.com', 'new window')")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
#driver.execute_script("window.open('https://bing.com/')")
driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("mad men")
driver.find_element_by_name("go").click()
#driver.implicitly_wait(3)

#search term 3 old enlish sheepdog
#this creates a new "pop out tab", and searches for "old englsh sheepdog"
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.bing.com',
'https://www.bing.com', 'new window')")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[2])
driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("old english sheepdog")
driver.find_element_by_name("go").click()
#driver.implicitly_wait(3)

#search term 4 phish fall 97 tour
# this gets this error code
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.bing.com',
'https://www.bing.com','https://www.bing.com', 'new window')")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[3])
driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("phish fall 97 tour")
drive r.find_element_by_name("go").click()
#driver.implicitly_wait(3)

print("Code Complete!")
```

Thanks for your help, I'm totally new:)